# Is the vocalic R and L pronounced the same in all Indian languages?

Tags: phonetics

Wondering what exactly is meant by the vocalic R and L in Oriya, Telugu, Malayalam, Tamil, and other related Indian languages. In many of these languages on Wikipedia, you find the IPA transcription as /ru/ or /lu/. In malayalam though, you find it as /rɨ/, etc.. For the R, is it really a combination of multiple more primitive sounds, or is it just like prolonging the "r" sound like in the English word "rrrrrrrrrread"? For the "l", same thing, is it just prolonging the "l" sound like in "llllllllearn". Or are these really pronounced as two blended sounds like "ru" and "lu"? And how do they differ from the consonant versions of these sounds? I get that the consonant version of "r" in these Indian languages is a flap, but the "l" also has a consonant, how does it differ from the vowel?

Finally, are these sounds all pronounced roughly the same in all Indian languages, or are there differences (as seen in Malayalam being /rɨ/ while the rest are /ru/)?

Comment: The answer to "is X the same in all Indian languages?" is almost always no. There are major linguistic differences.

Comment: Go here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Krishna#Translations , pick any Indian language, and inside its page you'll find the pronunciation of the vocalic R in that particular language. It will help you make a comparative chart yourself.

Comment: What's the -1 for, you may think that it's stupid to ask such a question, but as an amateur linguist I have no idea and am genuinely curious.

Comment: Maybe the downvote is for your asking too much: only the Constitution of India mentions _dozens_ of official languages.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but I agree with Yellow Sky: there are a LOT of languages spoken in India. And you already mention that Wikipedia provides different IPA transcriptions for them, which seems like pretty solid evidence that they're pronounced differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such thing in any non-resurrected spoken language of India, but there was in Sanskrit (I presume modern speakers of Sanskrit also pronounce *ṛ, ḷ* the way it was pronounced 2500 years ago or so). Original [r̩] underwent various sound changes between Sanskrit and the modern languages. But speakers of various languages of India may have to utter etymologically Sanskrit words. So the right question, then, would be "is the popular pronunciation of Sanskrit words influenced by one's native language" (you want to filter out modern trained speakers of Sanskrit), thus "How do people pronounce कृष्ण or however they spell it?". There are differences AFAIK. (Disclaimer: transcriptions are my own: limited-experiential, limited, not "official" and are not necessarily representative of all speakers). In Tamil, கிருஷ்ணா has more of an epenthetic vowel in k_r, compared to Hindi.

I propose that the answer is "nobody knows, but theoretically, we could find out". The first thing to do is collect some test words, like ऋषि. Then present the word to large samples of speakers of various Indian languages, and ask them to pronounce the word. You will have to bifurcate the experiment to present Tamil speakers with ரிஷி – as well as ऋषि (they may say "what *is* that?"). That is, responses might be influenced by your orthographic choice. Please do control the language demographics, because your Tamil speaker might be a professor of Sanskrit and your Telugu speaker might be bilingual in Maithli. With a large enough sample, you might be able to establish that speaker behavior is demonstrably influenced by first language (or dominant language, or whatever). What's crucial, IMO, is understanding what the askable question might even be. It's a question about how people respond to orthographic forms, for a peripheral linguistic fact (contemporary pronunciation of ancient phonemes). It is like asking how speakers of European languages pronounce Latin.